# include guard in ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the idiomatic way to add an include guard in a ruby file analogous to

```
#ifdef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
...

#endif
```

in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Chris Jester-Young says, `require` should be all you need. That said, you can use a simple `if` or similar as an "include" guard if you want to make yourself one, e.g.:

```
unless defined? FooGuard
  FooGuard = true
  ... rest of code ...
end
```

You can do anything in the body of the `if`, including define classes, methods, etc.

Answer (score 11):

If you use [`require`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Kernel.html#M001077) to load your file, it will only be included once (assuming you're not loading the same file by different names/paths), so in general Ruby files do not use include guards.